# is it possible to map a Map<String,String> in hibernate with @OneToMany relation?

Tags: hibernate, hibernate-mapping

i have a table

**Permission**:

- permission_id
- permission_name
- permission_desc

and a table **PermissionCategory** with one to many relation to **Permission**

is it possible to return map  in one to many relationship instead of list.
this is what i am doing right now in **PermissionCategory** domain:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
    @JoinTable(name = "perm_cat_map", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "perm_cat_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id") })
    private List<Permission> permissions = new ArrayList<Permission>(0);
```

is it possible to have something like:

```
@OneToMany(cascade = CascadeType.ALL, fetch = FetchType.LAZY)
        @JoinTable(name = "perm_cat_map", joinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "perm_cat_id") }, inverseJoinColumns = { @JoinColumn(name = "permission_id") })
        private Map<String,String> permissions = new ArrayList<String,String>(0);
```

where the two strings are **permission_id**, **permission_name**.

please advise, thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No: how would you add a new permission to this map ?

But you could have a `Map<String, Persmission>` (see http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/reference/en-US/html_single/#d0e10955), or you could add a specific method to your entity :

```
public Map<String, String> getPermissionMap() {
    Map<String, String> result = new HashMap<String, String>(permissions.size());
    for (Permission p : permissions) {
        result.put(p.getId(), p.getName());
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: i can't do the for loop solution coz it will make an overhead, that's why i am searching for an optimized way to do that, so talking about the first solution, can you tell me what is the string represents ?

Comment: It represents the key of the map. It could be any String property of the Permission entity, provided it's unique for a given category. Follow the link I gave you. I doubt the loop would be a performance issue. It's all in memory, whereas you have interprocess or even network operations each time you go to the database. We're talking microseconds vs. milliseconds here.

Answer (score 0):

http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.3/reference/en/html/collections.html